# Application_Begin Request not firing at all when published

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

When locally ran, this code runs fine. However when I publish the files in Release mode and place them in my wwwroot folder on my server, the application runs but the  Application_Begin Request method never fires. I tested it by creating a simple text file.

**EDIT:** I just created a simple exception in my Application_Start() method and that doesn't fire either. So my global.asax isn't firing. This is what is in my wwwroot folder

1. Areas folder (help files)
2. Bin Folder (all dlls and project files)
3. Global.asax
4. packages.config (nuget)
5. web.config

here is the application_start()

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
            CorsConfig.RegisterCors(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            var location = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
            var file = string.Concat(location, "/data.txt");
            using (var tw = new StreamWriter(file, true))
            {
                tw.WriteLine("Begin Request");
                tw.Close();
            }

            throw new Exception();               

        }
```

Im not sure if it is a dll or something that I am missing. I am using .Net 4.7.2

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            var location = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
            var file = string.Concat(location, "/data.txt");
            using (var tw = new StreamWriter(file, true))
            {
                tw.WriteLine("Begin Request");
                tw.Close();
            }
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                 Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                using (var tw = new StreamWriter(file, true))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine("Options Hit");
                    tw.Close();
                }
                Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Session, Authorization, USER_NBKID, Role, access-control-allow-credentials");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                Response.End();
            }                
        }
```

My webconfig has this section as well but it still isnt working

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
      <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
    </caching>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    **<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">** <---------------------
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://www.myaspwebsite.com" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-credentials, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization,USER_ID,UserRole" />
        <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
        <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
        <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(https?:\/\/((.+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.ap\.dk|(.+\.)?localhost(\:[0-9]*)?))" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
       <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      </handlers>   
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: `I tested it by creating a simple text file.` Did you search thoroughly for that text file?

Comment: yes i did. its a no go. Should create it write in the directory where the program is

Comment: Does `Path.Combine` rather than `string.Concat` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out it wasn't firing as this line in the web.config wasn't accurate

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

4.7.2 wasnt installed on the server so I changed it to

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

and its working. This took 3 days to figure out such a simple issue